# How to use Large Object in PostgreSQL to yeild a image field?

Tags: database, postgresql, blob

How does creating a large object work? Does there need to be a client, because all I am hoping to do is have an image be one column.
I am typing the following commands after creating my table but I just get an error about the path not being correct for the image (even though I have it starting right from the C drive).

```sql
CREATE TABLE image (name text,
                    raster oid);

INSERT INTO image (name, raster)
           VALUES ('beautiful image', lo_import('C:Documents/etc/motd'));
```

I am not running any C code, am I suppose to do that or does this automatically create the object Large Object?
If I am suppose to run some C code where would I do it with respect to PostgreSQL?

Can I do what I want all with PostgreSQL syntax? Is there another way to approach including images as a field?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PostgreSQL documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html), there's two ways to handle large objects (considering Java JDBC):

> To use the bytea data type you should simply use the getBytes(), setBytes(), getBinaryStream(), or setBinaryStream() methods.

and

> LargeObject API.

Also, you can covert your image to a base64 string and then insert it directly using, for instance, PgAdmin:

```sql
CREATE TABLE image_table (name varchar(255), DATA bytea);

INSERT INTO image_table
VALUES ('my_image.jpg',
        decode('paste your byte array string here', 'base64'));
```

[Full sample code here](http://pastebin.com/giQRF1xw).

Comment: where partial reads are not needed bytea is more efficient than largeobject.

Comment: but how would you use java or other code with Postgresql?
Also is there a way to get the image back with any of those options, the last option you suggest saved the data but now I am tring to extract the image but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Take a look at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html, there is two Java code samples .

Comment: Yes I saw this, but I need to know how to execute it in the pgAdmin interface because I am not using java for creating my database, so I am looking for the PostgreSQL code to implement this feature.

Comment: Can't you execute the select statement and then export the resulting data?

Comment: when you export the data is there a way to turn it back into an image, instead of have a string?

Comment: @Cleo, once you have a base64 string stored in your database column, decoding it back to binary and save them to a file, it will be an image again. Here's a tool for testing this: https://www.base64decode.org/